# Issue giving border:1px solid #CCC to my #site .home .stats .views li

Tags: html, css

Im trying to give border:1px solid #CCC to my `#site .home .stats .views li{}` but its not working fine.

My design breaks as you can see in my image:

[image]

Here I have my code without border: http://jsfiddle.net/jcak/L7qy4vh4/2/

And I want my structure as you see in fiddle but with border in my `#site .home .stats .views li{}`.

I already try do all math counts to hit right but my structure is always breaking with border:1px.

Can you help me giving understand how I can give a border without breaking my structure?

My Html:

```
<div id="site">
    <div class="content home">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="box_left stats">
                <h3>Website stats</h3>
                <div class="conteudo"> 
                    <ul class="views">
                        <li class="visitas">
                            1000
                            <small>Stats</small>
                        </li>
                        <li class="visitas">

                            1000
                            <small>Stats</small>
                        </li>
                        <li class="media" class="right">

                            1000
                            <small>Stats</small>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="views">
                        <li class="topic">
                            1000
                            <small>Stats</small>
                        </li>
                        <li class="comment">
                            1000
                            <small>Stats</small></li>
                        <li class="cats">1000
                            <small>Stats</small>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="views">
                        <li class="topic">
                            1000
                            <small>Stats</small>
                        </li>
                        <li class="comment">
                            1000
                            <small>Stats</small></li>
                        <li class="cats">1000
                            <small>Stats</small>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Css:

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}

#site{width:100%; background:#fff; min-height:300px; padding:20px 0;}

#site .content{width:1000px; margin:0 auto;}

#site .home .left{float:left; width:400px;}

#site .home .box_left{background:#eee; float:left; width:400px;}

#site .home .box_left h3{padding:15px; background:#ccc; font-size:22px; font-weight:400;  font-weight:bold;}

#site .home .box_left h3 a{float:right; text-transform:uppercase; margin-top:4px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; font-size:17px; color:#888;}

#site .home .box_left h3 a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}

#site .home .box_left .conteudo{padding:20px; width:400px; float:left;}

#site .home .stats{margin-bottom:30px;}

#site .home .stats .views{float:left; width:360px;list-style:none; background:#fbfbfb; position:relative;}

#site .home .stats .views li{float:left; text-align:center;  font-size:20px; width:60px;padding:30px 30px 30px 30px;}

#site .home .stats .views li small{display:block; font-size:13px; color:#000; }

#site .home .stats .views .right{float:right; margin-right:0;}
```

Comment: _"I already try do all math counts to hit right."_ What language is that??

Comment: do u want the borders to be consistent??

Comment: I want borders just a matter of design. And I was talking math counts, like counting the margins, paddings, etc so the border can fit without break my structure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of your requirement, if you want to align all li in one row, below change will will help you to overcome your problem

This is because, you have hardcoded `width` for `views`, increase width by 5-7px; Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L7qy4vh4/4/)**

Comment: Thanks, your solution was the solution that works best. But still I get a problem. I get more margin on the left side than the right. And I wanted it as it was, centered. But when I try to center my design breaks again!!

Comment: you can increase width box_left stats to 410px(or whatever you find appropriate). here is the working solution http://jsfiddle.net/L7qy4vh4/7/. Please remember to close this answer(by accepting the answer), if it solved your problem

Comment: Thank you really! I was here always breaking my structure without seeing the light! Thanks!

Comment: Most welcome Marby, good to hear that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `#site .home .stats .views li` to look like this:

```
#site .home .stats .views li {
  ...
  width: 120px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have div in div in div.... that is ok but can be messy. here is code. it works

```
site .home .stats .views{float:left; width:370px;list-style:none; background:#fbfbfb; position:relative;padding:0px;}
site .home .stats .views li{float:left; text-align:center;  font-size:20px; width:60px;padding:30px 30px 30px 30px;   border: 1px solid;}
```